# Trying to build an SQL statement for complex search scenario (Comparison)

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to build an SQL statement for a complex search scenario and I need you guys help. The scenario is:

I am trying to provide a service where Merchants will be signing up for it and provide the best value (most money) they will be offering for each product and then Users can provide their location and provide how much/how many kg of the each product they have and enter their values to a input form and then I want my SQL to list all the Merchants with the amount of money they will be offering in TOTAL where the most will start from the top.

I have a database with Merchants table & MerchantProducts table and Locations table. Every merchant have 20 products, and these products are same for every Merchant,

```
Merchant Table I have:
UserID (which is merchant's unique id)
MerchantName
MerchantTelNo
MerchantIsActive

MerchantProducts Table I have:
MerchantProductID
UserID
MerchantProductName
MerchantProductValue
MerchantProductLastUpdated
```

What I am trying to do is:

1- I have a Product form where users can enter the amount of product they have. Which is a list of products only includes a Name of the Product(Label) and Amount they have(textbox). The amount of products will be multiplied with the value of product.

2- User will enter his/her location.

3- SQL fill find the Merchants nearby and will list them where the most amount will be listed at top and the most least below it.

So far I have accomplished where a user will choose only one product and enter their location and I will get a return of one Merchant with the most amount offered. I have accomplished this with the following SQL Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNearbyLocations2] 
@ChosenProduct VARCHAR(100),
@CenterLatitude FLOAT, 
@CenterLongitude FLOAT, 
@SearchDistance FLOAT, 
@EarthRadius FLOAT AS DECLARE @CntXAxis FLOAT DECLARE @CntYAxis FLOAT DECLARE @CntZAxis FLOAT 
SET @CntXAxis = COS(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) * COS(RADIANS(@CenterLongitude)) 
SET @CntYAxis = COS(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(@CenterLongitude)) 
SET @CntZAxis = SIN(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) 


SELECT TOP 100 *,
ProxDistance = @EarthRadius * ACOS( dbo.XAxis(latitude, longitude)*@CntXAxis + dbo.YAxis(latitude, longitude)*@CntYAxis + dbo.ZAxis(latitude)*@CntZAxis) 
FROM MerchantProducts AS M INNER JOIN Locations AS L ON M.UserID = L.UserID INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(M.MerchantProductValue) AS MerchantProductValue FROM Locations AS L LEFT OUTER JOIN MerchantProducts AS M On L.UserID = M.UserID 
WHERE (M.MerchantProductName = @ChosenProduct AND @EarthRadius * ACOS( dbo.XAxis(latitude, longitude)*@CntXAxis + dbo.YAxis(latitude, longitude)*@CntYAxis + dbo.ZAxis(latitude)*@CntZAxis) <= @SearchDistance))
AS MX ON M.MerchantProductValue = MX.MerchantProductValue
AND M.MerchantProductName = @ChosenProduct
AND latitude IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ProxDistance ASC
```

I am trying to create a stored procedure to accomplish no. 1,2 & 3. Basically I want the users to enter how many kg of that product they have for each product and then I want sql to go through each Merchant and find out which merchant will give the most TOTAL amount of money for all of those products that a user entered value for in a list.

Thanks in advance and I hope I got my question through.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to create a stored procedure to accomplish no. 1,2 & 3. Basically i want the users to enter how many kg of that product they have for each product and then i want sql to go through each Merchant and find out which merchant will give the most amount of money in a list.

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you are trying to do, but you need to ask a specific question. This site isn't for people volunteering to do your work for you. What you have written is a specification, not a question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply JohnFx, yeah I understand, i wouldnt really expect someone to do my work for me, I just need an help in right direction or if there is a similar problem with a tutorial then I happy to take it from there. I am not too familiar with sql, any advise will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are describing is an optimization problem where you "fill an order based on location and price."  I think you may want to assign a "shipping cost" to each distance or else you may not be able to optimize for best prices and best locations simultaneously.

For a single product, you might be able to solve this elegantly using a recursive query which can be written using Common Table Expressions in SQL Server.  The first seed row within the CTE would be the user's location and full product quantity.  Then the recursive part pulls the top ranked row from a query that lists the combined cost of location and qty * price and subtracts the available amount from the seed row creating a second row with the remaining product quantity.  It then repeats until no quantity left.  Its kind of wild because probably need to avoid including the same merchant more than once by using the merchant lists from the previous rows.  I think there will always be a top ranked merchant at each iteration so that helps.

For multiple products you might need to either start with a "seed" of more than one row (or multiple dynamic columns) or calculate each product separately and then merge the results.

Probably this process could also be accomplished more functionally using a loop, running variables, and temp tables if you prefer.

[Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)